# why android studio change after few times restart on mac?

Tags: android-studio

i am new on mac. i have mac os x sierra 10.13.
i just install the android studio from the official site the latest one and when i install it when i create new project it looks like this [here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjsD5.png)
but when i open it after 3 to 4 times restart its UI changes and it act wiered  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCNFu.jpg) i dont know why .
and it evens the change the main Ui of it . 
how to resolve so it will not changed .